# group_by combined with frq() is excluding NAs from group variables, but I want to keep them

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm outputting summary statistics using frq() because my dataset has haven labels that I want displayed. I found that when I used group_by and run this, however, the output excludes groups with missing values. Reproducible example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(sjmisc)

look<-cars
    look<-look %>% mutate(color=case_when(
      speed > 10 ~ 'red',
      TRUE ~ 'blue'
    ))
 temp<-data.frame(speed=12,dist=12)
 look<-bind_rows(look,temp)
 rm(temp)
    
 look<-look %>% group_by(color) %>% frq(speed)
 look<-as.data.frame(look)
 sum(look$frq)
```

> [1] 50

Here we see that only 50 rows are summarized and the one with is.na(color) is excluded.

Is there any way to get groups with NA to show?

Thanks!

Comment: Also - I wanted to note - in this example I could just recode the NA to something else, but for the actual application I'm running frq on labeled variable (an imported SPSS dataset) and cannot simply recode NA (I get the error x must be a character vector, not a `haven_labelled/vctrs_vctr/double` object)

Comment: Have you tried coercing your imported variables to `factor()` first and then recode them? It seems like recoding those `NA` values is probably what you'd want to do here....

Comment: I think `haven::as_factor()` might be your way out.